# Passing X-Api-Key through file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to get data from a JSON endpoint on my streaming server. I've read that i need to pass an API key through the X-API-Key header. But not sure how to do this.

```
$url = file_get_contents('XXXXX/history');
$data1 = json_decode($url,true);
var_dump($data1);
```

this code works for me when getting json data from files that dont require the api key. How ever this now returns NULL as the key isn't being submitted through.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to provide the 3.rd parameter appropriately, `$context`

Comment: It needs context resource. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$url = 'XXXXX/history';
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$yourApiKey
));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is just returning NULL

Comment: how is your api key?

Answer (score 1):

try with CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'XXXXX/history');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000); // 3 sec.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); // 10 sec.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: ' . $yourApiKey
                ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


print_r($result);
```